# JSON: Instead of {"result":true} i get just true ( asp.net web api )

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web api to create service that android can use, so I need json because of parsing. But, I have a problem with methode login.

Other methods are fine, but in login I get just true, instead {"result":true}.

I know that json get pair key and value, where key is string and value is one of primitive types. But still I dont know why I dont get key as well.... I am new in asp.net and I am using json for the first time, so sorry if this question is too easy....

**Here's my login method:**

```
bool resulte = false;

    public bool ValidateLogin(string Username, string Password) 
    {


        if (Username.Equals("Admin") && Password.Equals("pass123"))
        {
            resulte = true;
            return resulte;
        }
        else 
        {
            resulte = false;
            return resulte;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public Response ValidateLogin(string Username, string Password) 
    {
        Response result=new Response();

        if (Username.Equals("Admin") && Password.Equals("pass123"))
        {
            result.Result= true;
            return result;
        }
        else 
        {
            result.Result= false;
            return result;
        }
    }
public class Response()
{
   private bool Result {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This can be solution just I will edit it a little bit so it will be completely correct!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own json string and return from method.

I have changed your code..

```
bool resulte = false;

    public string ValidateLogin(string Username, string Password)
    {


        if (Username.Equals("Admin") && Password.Equals("pass123"))
        {
            resulte = true;
            return "{\"result\":true}";
        }
        else
        {
            resulte = false;
            return "{\"result\":true}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not ok because now instead of true it's "{\"result\":true}" writen with " " :(

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...lets try to make it more generic, like

```
private string GetJsonFromBool(bool value)
{
    var data = new { result = value };
    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.
        JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
}

// Then use it at your return statement of original method, like
return GetJsonFromBool(true); // or false
```

Hope this helps...